# json file location in command prompt

Tags: json, node.js, angular

I am trying angularjs-2 for the first time from the example [found here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/angularjs-2-0-from-beginning-introduction-of-angular-js-2-0/)

and everything was working fine until I came to a point where the author has written something like this

> Now open the package.json file location in command prompt and execute
>   the below command to load the required modules and supported files
>   which are mentioned in the package.json file.
>
> npm start

after reading this I open command prompt by pressing `window+R` and write `cmd`
and I enter the following path

> E:....\nodejs with angular2 testing\nodejs with
>   angularjs2\nodejs with angularjs2\

but i am not able to do anything after this point

how can i execute the package from command prompt,?

i tried the same with developer command promt but facing the same issue,

hey guys i know i am bad in english but please i need help here

Comment: you can create a `package.json` file by running `npm init` in command prompt.

Comment: @Pete `package.json` is already there in the example package.

Comment: You're actually entering `E:....\nodejs with angular2 testing\nodejs with angularjs2\nodejs with angularjs2\`? What did you expect that to do?

Comment: @torazaburo yes `package.json` is already there,

but i am not able to understand how can i run `package.json` in command prompt(i never use command prompt or angular2 and json as i am c# developer)

Comment: @torazaburo Okay. Then I think he just need to run `npm install` to get required dependencies. right?

Comment: You do not run `package.json`. The instructions are telling you to run `npm start` **in the same directory as** `package.json`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to have `nodejs` in your system.

If you don't have `nodejs`, then [download](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) it. which shifts `npm` with it. [It is similar kind of stuff what `nuget` does in VisualStudio.]

As you mentioned `package.json` is already there in your project then you need to got to you `Application` folder in command prompt to install packages by running `npm install`.

**For example :** If your App folder is in `E:\Project\Myangular2App`,
then after opening `Command Prompt` with `window+R`, navigate to E drive by `E:`, then navigate to your App folder by  `cd Project\Myangular2App` and run `npm install`. This will install all the packages mentioned in `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

`start` seems to be a script configured in your package.json which probably runs something else.

Please state if npm (the node package manager) runs on your CLI without any argument. If not you have to get npm working first. It has to be in your $PATH variable in order to function anywhere.